# Pandas: How to handle timezone offset using 'DatetimeIndex'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

`(Not a duplicate question)`

In this question, I am using `Python3` and `Pandas`

In my raw dataset, the `datetime` was in `GMT`

`datetime` format: `2017-01-01 00:00:00`

I converted the `GMT` `datetime` into `EST` by doing this:

```
df['Gmt time'] = df['Gmt time'].dt.tz_localize('GMT').dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
```

The new `datetime` now look like this:

`2016-12-31 19:00:00-05:00`

now when I do:

`df['Gmt time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Gmt time'])`

I get this error:

`TypeError: [datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 31, 19, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))`

I tried to fix it by doing this:

`df['Gmt time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Gmt time'], tz='EST')` to speficy that the `datetime` is in `EST`

That is not working. How do I fix it? I need the end 'datetime' to be in `EST`

Comment: What does "but it is not working" mean? You will not get this error if everything else is correct imo.

Comment: Updated my question: The DF is correct. But because of `datetime` having an offset value, the `DatetimeIndex` is not working. I need somehow to remove the offset value or make the `DF` consider the `datetime` is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one out using pytz, its saving your data as Pacific and converting to Eastern, you can use the same and convert from GMT to any time zone.

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz
data = ['2017-01-01 00:00:00']
datatf= pd.to_datetime(data)
my_timestamp = dt.datetime.now()
new_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
old_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
my_timestamp_in_new_timezone = old_timezone.localize(datatf[0]).astimezone(new_timezone)
print(my_timestamp_in_new_timezone )
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Gmt time'] = [my_timestamp_in_new_timezone]
df['Gmt time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Gmt time'])
print(df)
```

Result :

```
               Gmt time
0 2016-12-31 21:00:00-08:00
```